# hive looks for hdfs private directory for jar

Tags: jar, hive, hdfs

How does add jar work in hive? when I add a local jar file, 
    add jar `/users/course/jars/json-serde-1.3.1.jar`;

hive query fails and says it could not find the jar in hdfs, same directory.
    Job Submission failed with exception `'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/users/course/jars/json-serde-1.3.1.jar)`

Then I put the jar into hdfs, add jar using that hdfs filepath. 
    add jar `hdfs://localhost/users/course/jars/json-serde-1.3.1.jar;`

Now, hive query says

```
File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/private/var/folders/k5/bn104n8s72sdpg3tg7d8kkpc0000gn/T/a598a513-d7c9-4d55-9280-b6554487cac7_resources/json-serde-1.3.1.jar
```

I have no idea why it keeps looking for the jar in wrong places.

Comment: Same issue here, except I am uploading the jar into hdfs as well as the text file I am using for table creation. Hue/Hive looks for both in the `private/var/....` described by OP. Whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Hive looks for the JAR locally, not on HDFS.

So if my home directory on the gateway server is

```
pwd
/home/my_username/
```

And the JAR is sitting locally at:

```
/home/my_username/hive_udfs/awesomeness.jar
```

Then I'd go into the hive shell and run:

```
add jar /home/my_username/awesomeness.jar
```

At least, that works for me in my environment. HTH. Good luck! :)